How to get the analytical form of a solution to an algebraic equation?
The real analytical solution of the algebraic equation $x^5 + 10 x^3 + 20 x == 4$ is $x=-2^{2/5} + 2^{3/5}$, how to get it with Mathematica?
I've tried with Solve, but it returns x -> Root[-4 + 20 # + 10 #^3 + #^5& , 1, 0] in its original form.

The analytical solution is obtained by let $x=t-2/t$, so that $t^5-32/t^5==4$, then it is easy to solve it. But I believe and hope that smart Mathematica can get the analytic form of this concise solution without me prompting this trick.

The code is shown below.
eqn = x^5 + 10 x^3 + 20 x == 4;
SolveValues[eqn, x, Reals]
Solve[eqn /. x -> t - 2/t, t, Reals];
t - 2/t /. % // Simplify


This can now be done with the resource function RadicalDenest. `In[20]:= val =
First[SolveValues[x^5 + 10  x^3 + 20  x == 4, x, Reals]];
ResourceFunction["RadicalDenest"][val]
Out[20]= 2^(2/5) (-1 + 2^(1/5))`

Using answer in Solving quintic in radicals
QuinticToRadicals[sol[[1]]]

gives

Full code (see post above)
QuinticToRadicals[root_Root].....

Now to use it, just do
eqn=x^5+10 x^3+20 x==4;
sol=SolveValues[eqn,x];
QuinticToRadicals[sol[[1]]]

For all the roots it gives
Map[QuinticToRadicals,sol]// Column



The simplest approach relies on observation that our polynomial  $x^5 + 10 x^3 + 20 x -4$ is of the fifth order with integer coefficients divisible by $2$ (beside one with the highest order power). And so it is natural to look for its factorization with Extension $2^{1/5}$:
Factor[x^5 + 10 x^3 + 20 x - 4, Extension -> 2^(1/5)]


We can see a factor $(x-(2^{3/5}-2^{2/5}))$
and so it becomes clear that $2^{3/5} - 2^{2/5}$ is a real root of the polynomial
Simplify[ x^5 + 10 x^3 + 20 x - 4 /. x -> -2^(2/5) + 2^(3/5)]


0


Q.E.D.
All complex solutions one can get with
Factor[x^5 + 10 x^3 + 20 x - 4, Extension -> {2^(1/5), (-1)^(1/5)}]

or in explicitly complex form ( the output in TeXForm)
ComplexExpand /@ Factor[ x^5 + 10 x^3 + 20 x - 4,
                         Extension -> {2^(1/5), (-1)^(1/5)}]

$$-\left(\left(-x+2^{3/5}-2^{2/5}\right) \\ \left(-x+i \left(2^{2/5}
   \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}+2^{3/5}
   \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2\ 2^{2/5}}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2\
   2^{3/5}}-\frac{1}{2\ 2^{2/5}}+\frac{1}{2\ 2^{3/5}}\right)\\ \left(-x+i \left(2^{2/5}
   \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}+2^{3/5}
   \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2\ 2^{2/5}}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2\
   2^{3/5}}-\frac{1}{2\ 2^{2/5}}+\frac{1}{2\ 2^{3/5}}\right)\\ \left(x+i \left(2^{2/5}
   \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}+2^{3/5}
   \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2\ 2^{2/5}}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2\
   2^{3/5}}+\frac{1}{2\ 2^{2/5}}-\frac{1}{2\ 2^{3/5}}\right)\\ \left(x+i \left(2^{2/5}
   \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}+2^{3/5}
   \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2\ 2^{2/5}}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2\
   2^{3/5}}+\frac{1}{2\ 2^{2/5}}-\frac{1}{2\ 2^{3/5}}\right)\right)$$

Here is a way to do the manipulations in Mathematica/Wolfram Language:
eqn = x^5 + 10  x^3 + 20  x - 4 == 0
eqn2 = SubtractSides[
   MultiplySides[FullSimplify[eqn /. x -> (t - 2/t)], t^5][[1, 1, 
      1]] // Simplify, 32 + 4 t^5] // Expand
eqn3 = eqn2 /. t -> u^(1/5)
is = u /. Solve[eqn3, u];
res = DeleteDuplicatesBy[
   a - 2/a /. Join @@ (Solve[a^5 == #, a] & /@ is), N];
Extract[res, Position[N[res], _Real]][[1]]


